# 06B chain on #35 type sprocket

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chain

I can't find a 16 teeth sprocket with hub and 18mm bore for 06B roller chain. There are sprockets for ANSI #35 chains with these specifications, though. The pitch is practically the same, the roller has a bit smaller diameter (5.08mm vs. 6.35mm) and is a bit narrower (4.77mm vs. 5.72mm). #35 sprocket will fit 06B chain with some lateral slack. Is this substitution going to work in a light application with about 10lbs chain tension?

Comment: Will the thinness cause the chain to tip and wear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not going to mesh properly because of the different roller diameter. I put a quick sketch together to illustrate it:

[image: #35-6B-chain]

The rounded tooth base is made to match the diameter of the chain roller, and only in the tooth base the pitch is correct. The rollers of the 6B chain are too large to fit into the tooth base of a #35 sprocket, so the rollers need to climb up on the tooth flanks to still fit. In the climbed-up position, the pitch doesn't match anymore, so this chain can never properly mesh with the sprocket.

American Standard and British Standard (which the DIN ISO 606 orientates on) chains appear similar, but are not interchangable. You need to either find a 6B sprocket to fit your machine or change the entire chain drive to #35.

Comment: Works for me. plus 1